# Connecting With pc via USB

Tags: usb

I use Symphony w71.Though it would connect with PC but after root I find no option to connect with PC.It charge but not connect with computer.My phone debug option is on also enabling Root permission.What should I do now??

Comment: What kind of PC are you using? Does it have drivers installed?

Comment: By no option, do you mean the connection is not visible on your pc? And have you tried mtp connection?

Comment: Your device is already connected and detected if it's charging. Please edit and clarify that what you're asking is access to storage of Android from PC.

Answer (score 1):

Once you connect your phone to your PC, unlock your phone and follow these steps

Pull down the **Status/Notification bar**. You must be able to see the type of connection. Press on it.

You must be able to see several options like **Media device(MTP)**,  **Camera(PTP)**, **Charge only** and **Mass storage(UMS)**.

For your requirements, I suggest you choose the **MTP** connection. The UMS would just mount your SD card as an external device and ignore the internal storage.

You must be able to view your phone being connected to your PC by now and I would suggest you keep your screen unlocked till you disconnect your phone from the PC

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should only use an other usb-cable. Many cables have the middle two pins (which are for the data) in a position were it does not connect to pc, but the both pins left and right(which are for the power) are connected. So your device is loading but your pc says there is no mobile phone connected. Sorry but in my opinion many manufacturer do this with purpose :/
[image: USB pins explanation]
Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Welcome to Android enthusiasts. OP is facing the issue after rooting the phone. This does not answer the question